# Java: Condition not checked on empty while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have two empty while loops that are waiting for the user to perform an action on two buttons. Once a button is pressed, the boolean used for the while condition is set to true, and the program proceeds.

Code is like this:

```
public class test {
    static JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    static JButton yes = new JButton("Yes");
    static boolean isSendButtonPressed = false;
    static boolean isYesButtonPressed = false;
    //...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        send.addActionListener(new sendListener());
        yes.addActionListener(new yesListener());
        //...
        while (!isSendButtonPressed) {} //works
        System.out.println("Send button pressed");
        while (!isYesButtonPressed) {} //doesn't work
        System.out.println("Yes button pressed");

}

class sendListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        test.isSendButtonPressed = true;
    }
}
class yesListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        test.isYesButtonPressed = true;
    }
}
```

So, when I press the "send" button, `isSendButtonPressed` is set to true, and it prints the statement. However it doesn't do that for the "yes" button, unless I put an instruction (for example, a System.out.println) inside the while loop. I honestly don't see why the first works but not the second, or why it would need an useless instruction to work.

Comment: This is a **horrible** way to wait for input...

Comment: Please don't busy loop.  Even if you make those `boolean`s volatile, it's a horribly bad idea.   Just `Object.wait()` on a mutex, and have the button handler notify that mutex.

Comment: you should make isYesButtonPressed (and isSendButtonPressed) `volatile`

Comment: @ControlAltDel, no no no.  The problem is much larger than missing a `volatile`.  The problem is that busy looping is a terrible idea.  People use devices that depend on batteries.  Don't make workstations suck, and don't chew up mobile devices batteries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

['The Infamous "Unresponsive User Interface"'](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j5e_multithreading.html) explains how to use `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` to communicate across threads.

The java memory model allows field changes not to be visible unless the field is `volatile`, so changing a non-volatile `boolean` field in the UI thread is not guaranteed to cause a loop condition to change until both threads end up obtaining/releasing a lock.

Comment: Thanks, set the booleans to volatile and it now works. Do an empty while loop consume a lot of battery though? It's just a personal app, nothing much important.

Comment: @Zezombye, see the busy looping section of [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops)

Comment: Also, if you need to do anything more complex than writing to System.out then you probably need to synchronize on some shared object.